# undefined argument passed to a fn in custom react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using a custom hook to open a modal which will perform different actions.

To open and close the modal im using the custom hook `useSongUtils` methods `openModal` and `closeModal`:

```
export const useSongUtils = () => {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  const openModal = ({ cellData }) => {
    // outputs undefined
    console.log('cell data is', cellData);
    setIsEditing(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsEditing(false);
  };

  return {
    closeModal, isEditing, setIsEditing, openModal,
  };
};
```

And then importing the returned object into my component, where I have a method for a `VirtualTable` that renders some action links.

The cell data is an id and it is displayed correctly in the `optionsRender` method (both links work - I get the id). However, the idea is that clicking the `Button` element, calls the `openModal` method from `usesongUtils` and sets `isEditing` to true. That works.

However I'm also trying to get the `cellData` arguments in `openModal` method and it is not working. I'm getting `undefined` if I try to `console.log`.

```
  // SongList.js

  const optionsRender = ({ cellData }) => (
    <div className='songs-list__options'>
      <Link to={`/songs/${cellData}/edit`}>
        <Icon name='edit' style={{ margin: '0 .2rem .2rem 0' }} />
      </Link>
      <a rel='noreferrer' target='_blank' href={`localhost/client/song/${cellData}`}>
        <Icon name='play' style={{ margin: '0 .2rem' }} />
      </a>
      {cellData} // I can see the data!!
      // im trying to pass cellData to openModal 
      <Button size='tiny' className='ui button' fluid icon='setting' circular onClick={() => openModal(cellData)} />
    </div>
  );

  const {
    closeModal, isEditing, openModal,
  } = useSongUtils();
```

Comment: What do you get for `props` if you change `const optionsRender = ({ cellData }) => (...` to `const optionsRender = (props) => (...`?

Comment: You seem to be destructuring the `cellData`  in `openModal`?

Comment: lord, that was it, i was destructuring something that shouldn't be. Sorry. Never saw that.

Comment: @FerToasted happens to the best of us haha